# Scrapy repeating scraped data

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm new to python but need to scrape for work related reasons. Have spent a week or two on scrapy and am finally content with it except that the following code, instead of outputting one line of data, repeats it five times. Here is an example (using only 1 url):

import scrapy

```
class AdamSmithInstituteSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "adamsmithinstitute"
start_urls = [
"https://www.adamsmith.org/research?month=March-2018",

]


def parse(self, response):
    for quote in response.css('div.post'):
        yield {
            'author': response.css('post-author::text').extract(),
            'pdfs': response.selector.xpath('//div/div/div/div/div/div/div/p/a').extract(),
        }

    next_page = response.css("div.older a::attr(href)").extract_first()
    if next_page is not None:
        next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
        yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

The output in the scrapy shell is as follows:

```
2018-07-10 11:53:12 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 
https://www.adamsmith.org/research?month=March-2018>
{'author': [], 'pdfs': ['<a target="_blank" href="/s/Immigration1.pdf">Read 
the full paper</a>']}
2018-07-10 11:53:12 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 
https://www.adamsmith.org/research?month=March-2018>
{'author': [], 'pdfs': ['<a target="_blank" href="/s/Immigration1.pdf">Read 
the full paper</a>']}
2018-07-10 11:53:12 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 
https://www.adamsmith.org/research?month=March-2018>
{'author': [], 'pdfs': ['<a target="_blank" href="/s/Immigration1.pdf">Read 
the full paper</a>']}
2018-07-10 11:53:12 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 
https://www.adamsmith.org/research?month=March-2018>
{'author': [], 'pdfs': ['<a target="_blank" href="/s/Immigration1.pdf">Read 
the full paper</a>']}
2018-07-10 11:53:13 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 
https://www.adamsmith.org/research?month=March-2018>
{'author': [], 'pdfs': ['<a target="_blank" href="/s/Immigration1.pdf">Read 
the full paper</a>']}
```

I am aware that the data is messy as I only want the href link but am familiar enough to figure that out myself. What I can't put my finger on is the repeating.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Scrapy only takes care of url duplication if an item is being repeated then the developer has to remove the duplication

scrapy has documented duplication filter pipeline,
[click here read it](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#duplicates-filter)

In that example they have show an id as a unique where in your case it could be different one

Answer (score 0):

You're using **ABSOLUTE** path in your CSS expressions. So each of your expresssion search in the WHOLE document (starting from the beginning). You need to apply your expressions to the `quote`:

```
for quote in response.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "post")]'):
    yield {
        'author': quote.xpath('.//div[@class="post-author"]/text()').extract_first(),
        'pdfs': quote.xpath('.//here/I'm/not/sure/in/expression/text()').extract_first(),
    }
```

Comment: Hey, thanks - that's great! Any tips on finding the relative xpath (im assuming that's what you've done) for the pdf links?

Comment: Ah, apologies; I will be scraping successive pages with the same structure. https://www.adamsmith.org/research is an example; hence why the relative xpath would be useful.

Comment: Something like this `'.//a[.="Read the full paper"]/@href'`